# How to reflect values in jtable same as from another table in java?

Tags: swing, jtable

I have two tables, UPPER and LOWER. LOWER table can be dynamically changed by selecting from one combo box.
LOWER combo box items are "A","B".
Here if selected items are "A", both LOWER and UPPER table value should be same. My question is
if I am editing UPPER table value,by the same time same value should be reflected in LOWER table also.
Examle

```
UPPER TABLE
S.No   Default Value User Value
 1          58.5        65.0 
 2          20.5        40.0

LOWER TABLE
Combobox value is 'A' 
S.No   Default Value User Value
 1          58.5        65.0 
 2          20.5        40.0
```

if I am editing UPPER table **user value**, by the same time same value should be reflected in LOWER table **user value** also.

How to do in JTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let both tables share the same instance of TableModel

```
 if ("A".equals(combo.getSelectedItem()) {
    lower.setModel(upper.getModel()); 
 } else {
   // do whatever
 }
```